# How to manage firebase real-time database when you use phone authentication ? Android studio using kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using this [sample code](https://github.com/Aniskonig/Phone-Authentication-firebase) to let users sign in using only there phone number but i need more informations from them like there name and gender...In the past when i was using email for sign in i used to use this code to add those informations :

```
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val user = User(
                    name,
                    email,
                    gender,
                        0.0.toFloat(),0.0.toFloat(),0.0.toFloat(),0.0.toFloat(),"","",
                        isSameDay().isTheDay())
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<Void> { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Enregistré avec succès", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            mProgressbar.dismiss()
                            sendEmailVerification()
                            startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))
                        }
                    })
            } else {

                if (isConnected() && task.exception.toString() == "com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: The email address is already in use by another account."){
                    mRegisterEmail.error = "Cette adresse email est déjà utilisée par un autre compte!"
                }else if (isConnected()){
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Echec! \n ${task.exception.toString()}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                if(!isConnected()){
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Connecter à Internet, SVP!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                mProgressbar.dismiss()

            }
        }
}
```

> So please help me to find the way to add the same information while
>   using phone authentication..you can push it directly in my project
>   [here](https://github.com/Aniskonig/Phone-Authentication-firebase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using this code thank you

```
>            user = User(
>                 name,
>                 "email@gmail.com",
>                 gender.text.toString(),
>                 0.0.toFloat(),0.0.toFloat(),0.0.toFloat(),0.0.toFloat(),"","",
>                 isSameDay().isTheDay())
>             FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
>                 .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
>                 .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<Void> { task
> ->
>                     if (task.isSuccessful) {
>                         Toast.makeText(this, "Enregistré avec succès", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
>                         mProgressbar.dismiss()
>                     } else {
>                                     Log.e("TAG", "create Account: Fail! ", task.exception)
>                                     Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Echec! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
>                     }
>                 })
```